# What is a short, simple, useful, cool, impressive, or geeky Ruby code?

Tags: ruby

For examples,

```
@second = 2
@foo = @first || @second || @third
p @foo #=> 2
```

and

```
p [1, 2, 3].map(&:to_s) #=> ["1", "2", "3"]
```

I'm looking forward to reading an interesting code! 
Thanks :)

Comment: isn't this the very definition of subjective.  should at least be CW

Answer (score 9):

A function that checks if an integer `n` is prime using regex!

```
def is_prime(n)
    ("1" * n) !~ /^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$/
end
```

Explanation and source [here](http://www.noulakaz.net/weblog/2007/03/18/a-regular-expression-to-check-for-prime-numbers/).

Comment: Just read the explanation. I HAVE to upvote this one more time.

Comment: Wow, it's powerful and beautiful!
And thanks for putting the reference.

Comment: It's also older than ruby.  I'm pretty sure this regex first appeared in one of Abigail's sigs in the comp.lang.perl.misc newgroup sometime in the 90's.

Comment: Glad you folks liked it... if you are planning to use it to do work with prime numbers, keep in mind Ruby has a prime generator built in.

Comment: Here's an article on its use in real life settings: http://zmievski.org/2010/08/the-prime-that-wasnt

Answer (score 1):

```
class Array
  def to_hash; Hash[*map {|x| [x, yield(x)] }.flatten]; end
end
```

**(Edit)** Here is a more verbose version:

```
class Array
  def to_hash
    keys_and_values = self.map {|x| [x, yield(x)] }
    # Now `keys_and_values` is an array of arrays reperesenting
    # the hash. If the array this method was called on was, for
    # example, `[1, 2, 3]`, and the block passed to this method
    # was `{|x| x + 1 }`, `keys_and_values` would be:
    #
    #     [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]


    keys_and_values = keys_and_values.flatten
    # now `keys_and_values` still contains all of the keys/values
    # of the new hash, but without the inner arrays. Even numbered
    # indexes will be keys, and odd indexes will be values. Example:
    #
    #     [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]


    Hash[*keys_and_values]
    # This returns the keys/values translated to a hash. The docs
    # for the `Hash.[]` method is here:
    #
    #     http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M002839
  end
end
```

Comment: Wow, it looks like very geeky! I'm sorry but I can't understand this code. What's going on? If possible, I'd like to read a lengthy code of this.

And I tried to use this code with the following one. Is it nice usage?
    ["abc", "def", "ghi"].to_hash { |i| "same" } #=> {"abc"=>"same", "def"=>"same", "ghi"=>"same"}

Thanks.

Comment: @bekkou68: See my edit, which explains it.

Answer (score 0):

using enum.zip and block:

```
class Array
  def to_hash(&b)
    Hash[*self.zip([b.call]*self.size).flatten]
  end
end
#[1,2,3].to_hash{'n'} >> {1=>'n',2=>'n',3=>'n'}
```